# Magento 2 Configurable product images showing with child products

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento2.2

I added images in magento 2 configurable product and then I added 3 child products with images but on product detail page after selected child product it is showing both images (parent and child product), I want to show only child product images if selected otherwise parent's product images. Is there any patch to do this?